# Why do physicists, in quantum mechanics, call average an expectation value, not expected value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, terminology, probability, statistics

I guess there is a specific reason for this - calling the expected observation $$\langle\psi|\hat{Q}|\psi\rangle$$ (for a normalised wavefunction) an **expectation value**.

I heard somewhere that, in quantum mechanics, the term **expected value** is used instead to indicate the point where the probability density, $|\psi(\vec{r}, t)|^2$, is at the maximum. Firstly, is it correct?

Secondly, if so, why do you think this kind of distinction between the two jargons started among physicists?

Comment: Do you have a source? That doesn't sound like standard terminology to me.

Comment: @jacob1729 Like, just google it. You will see millions of uses.

Comment: To clarify, expectation value is standard terminology and is in accordance with what everyone uses in classical probability theory. I'm objecting to 'expected value' having any consistent technical meaning.

Comment: Anecdotally, I use expected value and expectation value interchangeably to mean $\langle \psi ,Q\psi\rangle/\Vert \psi\Vert^2$.  I have never seen or heard of anybody using it to refer to the maximum of $|\psi(r)|^2$.

Comment: The maximum of the probability density is an overrated concept, since the location of the maximum depends on your choice of variables. It's better to talk about quantities that have a more invariant meaning, like the expectation value (for what it's worth I would interpret "expectation value" and "expected value' as referring to the same quantity)

Comment: @curious why do we have to do even more work to figure out where you heard distinct terminology to answer your question? It would benefit everyone if you to just provide some example sources where you saw the different terminology.

Comment: @Triatticus It was a recorded lecture on YouTube by Leonard Susskind. But please bear in mind that my memory might be really inaccurate. I didn't want to make a great physicist a fool by providing wrong information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How expected value is used in QM is exactly how it is used in regular probability (this holds for both discrete and continuous probabilities). It is easier to explain for the discrete case but I can link an explanation for the continuous case as well (its pretty much the exact same thing).

If $A$ has a complete set of eigenvectors $| \phi _{j} \rangle$, with eigenvalues $ a_{j}$, then the for some general $ |\psi \rangle = \sum_{i}c_i | \phi _{i} \rangle$, by the statistical definition of expected value we want E.V.[$A$]=$\sum_{i} |c_i|^2a_i$, this is because we have a $|c_i|^2$ chance of finding our state in $| \phi _{i} \rangle$, which has associated observable $ a_{i}$

Now lets define the notation $\langle A \rangle_{\psi} = \langle \psi |A|\psi \rangle$, therefore:

$$\langle A \rangle_{\psi} = \sum_{i,j}c_ic_j^* \langle \phi_j |A|\phi_i \rangle = \sum_{i,j}c_ic_j^* a_i\langle \phi_j|\phi_i \rangle = \sum_{i,j}c_ic_j^* a_i \delta_{i,j} = \sum_{i}c_ic_i^* a_i = \sum_{i} |c_i|^2a_i $$

Notice this is only the EV of $A$ when acting on $| \psi \rangle$, if you have a different state, you have a different probability distribution and thus a different EV, but essentially the expected value as we defined in using Dirac notation is consistent with the idea of expected value in statistics.

To show this for continuous PDF, just represent your operator and state vector using integrals, and the same result should be obtained. Dirac notation really is magical!

See page 7 of this document for continuous observables: [http://physics.mq.edu.au/~jcresser/Phys301/Chapters/Chapter14.pdf](http://physics.mq.edu.au/%7Ejcresser/Phys301/Chapters/Chapter14.pdf)

This video is also very useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQKV-hpsurs

Comment: Where in that chapter is mentioned the term "expected value"?

Answer (score 3):

Both expectation value and expected value are misleading terms, because in general the value

$$
\langle x \rangle = \int dx~ \rho(x) x~~~~(*)
$$
based on probability distribution $\rho(x)$ is not some special value expected to occur more often or with certainty. In fact, this average value may be less probable to occur than other value, or even be the least probable to occur - this happens if $\rho(\langle x\rangle)$ has the global minimum value.

(*) is simply average value based on the probability distribution $\rho(x)$.

Standard terminology for this average value is "expectation value". I like "expected average" more, since in series of many measurements of $x$, average of results is expected to be close to $(*)$, and with increasing number of measurements, to converge to $\langle x \rangle$. In this sense (*) is "expected average".

Comment: Very nice insight :)

Comment: According to the German wikipedia, the use of the term "expectation" goes back to a Latin translation of a text from 1656 of Huygens, translated in 1657. So it has some tradition.  (Context: It is about the expected value of a game, i.e. how much money you expect to make in gambling.)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is merely a semantic choice; generally speaking the bracket you have written is precisely what is meant by the "expected/expectation" value. The terminology I have heard most often (in the context of quantum chemistry) for the maximal value of the probability function is the "most probable value" or something to that effect. I think this terminology is pretty clear, and I'm not sure where you found people using expected value in the problematic way posed in the question.